# Definition of the bias of an estimator

Tags: bias, estimators, unbiased-estimator, bias-variance-tradeoff

I'm quite confused about the definition of the **bias of an estimator**.

> Suppose we have unknown distribution $P(x, \theta)$, and construct the
> estimator $\hat{\theta}$ that maps the observed data sample to values
> that we hope are close to $\theta$. Then the bias of an estimator is
> defined by:
>
> $$Bias(\hat{\theta}) = \mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}) - \theta ,$$

How can we calculate the $Bias(\hat{\theta})$ if we know neither the parent distribution $P(x, \theta)$ nor the true value of parameter  $\theta$?

Is there a need for any assumptions?

---

**upd:** suppose I've proved, that estimator of the mean ($\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mx_i$) is unbiased for the Gaussian distribution, but is there any distribution for which the same estimator is biased? Or is it possible to prove such an estimator is unbiased for any distribution?

I guess such a question is caused by the lack of intuition about estimator and its bias. May be there is some convenient way to think about it?

Comment: Example: If $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma),$ then $E[\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2] = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2< \sigma^2,$ even if $\sigma^2>0$ unknown.

Comment: Of course, you need to make assumptions

Answer (score 1):

When we ask if an estimator is unbiased, it is important to add that it is unbiased for a given quantity $\theta$, so I would add that to the definition. On the calculation, you do the computations under the assumptions for the distribution you are working. It may have a parametric form or not.

To exemplify, let $F$ be a c.d.f. (playing the role of your $P(x, \theta)$), and assume we have an i.i.d. sample $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that $X_i \sim F$. The only hypothesis we will assume is that $\theta = E[X_1] = \int xdF$ exists. Notice something very important: the distribution $F$  is not parametrized by $\theta$. Indeed, our estimators are not necessarily for "parameters", but rather for functions of your distribution (usually functionals). For example, there are problems in which you are interested in estimating the density of $F$ (the p.d.f.), and you do not think of it as a "parameter" of $F$.

Now, lets show that $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$  is unbiased for $\theta$.

$$ E\left[\widehat{\theta}\right] = \frac{1}{n} E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\int xdF = \theta \quad.$$

We only used properties of the expectation, which hold for any $F$, even if we do not know its "exact form".

Have we proved then that the sample mean is unbiased for any statistical model? Not at all. For instance, $\theta$ might not be well defined! If $F$ ranges over a Cauchy family, then it does not make sense to estimate $\theta$.

A similar problem might arise if the sample is not i.i.d.: $\theta$ may not be defining exactly what you want, and even if it is, the estimator might not be unbiased. For example, suppose that $(Y_i)_{i=1}^n$ are i.i.d. with $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta, 1)$, but your sample is $\mathbf{X} = (X_i)_{i=1}^n$ with $X_i = (-1)^{n+1} Y_i$. If you want to estimate $\theta$, you actually have $\theta = E[X_1]$, so it is defined. However, the sample mean is not unbiased, as you can easily verify.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the bias as "if I repeat my experiment many times and apply my estimator each time, how much does the average estimation result differ from the true result?"

For example, the sample variance
$$
\hat{\sigma}_Y^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i-\bar{Y})^2 = \frac{N-1}{N} \sigma_Y^2
$$
is a biased estimator of the variance of a distribution, which means that *on average over many repeated experiments* it will under-estimate the true variance $\sigma_Y^2$. This does *not* mean that it will under-estimate it *every single time*.

To assess the biasedness or unbiasedness of the estimator, one will usually make some assumptions about $P(x, \theta)$. E.g., the [derivation of the biasedness of the sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance) assumes independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) measurements. The magnitude of the bias can in general depend on many factors such as the sample size $N$ and the true parameter vector $\theta$.

To put it another way, the bias of an estimator is something that is usually analyzed theoretically under specific assumptions. Therefore, one can assume full knowledge of the true parameters $\theta$ for the purpose of the derivation. In the above case of the sample variance, the bias is easy to correct (just multiply the resulting estimate by $\frac{N}{N-1}$), but in general this may not be possible, e.g., if the bias depends on the true parameter vector $\theta$.

As a sidenote, in many cases it may be desirable to use a biased estimator because, e.g., the mean squared error of a biased estimator may be lower than the mean squared error of an unbiased estimator. See, e.g., the [bias-variance trade-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff). One classical example is the [James-Stein estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator), which is biased but has a lower MSE than ordinary least squares, which is unbiased.

Comment: I think you must mean $\hat\sigma_Y^2.$

Comment: Of course, thanks! Corrected.

Comment: @Chuckha: The answers were fine but, in case this  part of your question wasn't answered,  the underlying distribution often does matter. For example, the mean is unbiased for the gaussian but it's not unbiased for say the chi-squared or the laplace.

Comment: @mlofton In general, I agree with "the distribution often does matter", but isn't the sample mean an unbiased estimator of the distribution mean for all distributions?

Comment: Mlofton is wrong. When population mean is defined sample mean is unbiased for all distributions. It is just not efficient if distribution is not Gaussian.

Comment: @Cagdas: I don't have time to go into it here but I'm not wrong. Work out ( or look up ) $ E(x)$  of the chi-squared or the laplace and you'll see that it's not the mean. Unbiasedness is very often a function of the underlying distribution.

Comment: @Cagdas Ozgenc : See "parameter estimation" section of this link. I have a very strong feeling that some function of the median ( maybe even the median itself )  is unbiased for the laplace.  https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366c.htm

Comment: @Cagdas Ozgenc: Here's a more thoughtful reason explaining why I'm not wrong. The concept of unbiasdness is linked to the expectation of the estimator since, for unbiasedness, one wants the expectation of the estimator to be equal to the mean of the distribution. But the expectation of the estimator has to depend on the underlying distribution because of the definition of expectation. I hope this helps.

Comment: @jhin: regarding your comment for the mean being unbiased for all distributions, unfortunately, no. What you say is true for  any perfectly symmetric distribution that doesn't involve absolute values. If a distribution doesn't satisfy the latter characteristics, then it's possible that the mean is not unbiased. Check out the link I sent. The unbiased estimator  for the laplace will involve the median rather than the mean. For the chi-squared, if X ~ chi-squared $k$, then it's  gamma(k/2, 1/2) and its mean is 2 * k/2 = k. So, the unbiased estimator is $k$ which is not the sample mean.

Comment: @mlofton proof is in Lucas’s answer. Your arguments are just vague explanations. Proof is very simple involving basic calculus and comes from linearity of expectation.

Comment: @mlofton Maybe he hasn't "admitted" to being wrong because he's not and you are? Lucas' answer literally shows that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean if the latter exists, without any assumptions on the underlying distributions. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Unbiasedness) says the same thing. The link you gave above regarding the exp. distribution says that the median is the ML estimate of the location parameter. That's fine. However, the sample mean is still an unbiased estimate of the same location parameter.

Comment: @mlofton The sample mean of a Chi-squared distribution is also an unbiased estimator of the population mean, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Sample_mean) for worked-out expressions.

Comment: @mlofton As Cagdas wrote, the sample mean is just not *efficient* anymore for many distributions.

Comment: @Jhin: according to the wiki, the sample mean of the chi squared is consistent for the parameter $k$ of the chi squared distribution. Consistent mean asymptotically unbiased so I'll admit that I'm wrong there. I'll check out the wiki for the laplace and get back to you. Hopefully, I'm not wrong there too.

Comment: I found a link which shows that, for the Laplace, E(X) = u. So the sample mean IS UNBIASED and doesn't even need asymptotics. So, my apologies to Cagdas and jhin for being wrong.  I was definitely wrong. And also apologies for making this thread so confusing. It seems that the sample mean is always atleast asymptotically unbiased for the first parameter of it's  distribution. News to me and thanks for teaching me something.  I'll remove my rude comment to Cagdas but leave the rest in so as not confuse the thread even more.

Comment: @mlofton Well, I also learned some new things, and I'm happy we've come to an agreement. :-)